# How can we use multiple <h:messages> tags or <h:message> tags in a single JSF page?

Tags: jsf

My problem is that I have 2 forms in a single JSF page each having its `<h:message>` or `<h:messages>` tag. As we know the message/messages tags print any validation errors, so what happens is, suppose I leave the fields of any of the 2 forms empty it should print "Fields cannot be left blank" or some kind of message. It gives this message, but it gives twice as there are two forms. So I see the same error/validation message at each of the two forms.

So what I need is the `<h:messages>` or the `<h:message>` tag should display error/validation message only once for each of their respective forms!!

So any help would greatly be appreciated!!

Comment: I warn you using two forms in a single page because ie does not support this feature

Comment: @mucayufa That would be a major bug in IE if it wouldn't support two forms on a page. Maybe you aimed at nested forms which is no valid HTML and can/will lead to errors in all browsers.

Comment: Are you using nested forms? Please provide a sample jsf code of your page. Did you try `<rich:message` component together with `for` attribute?

Comment: @Matt ı do not mean nested forms. I used two separete forms in a single page, but ie compatibility problem came out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using JSF 2, then you could just submit and update the form by ajax. This allows for partially updating the view.

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    ...
    <h:commandButton ...>
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    ...
    <h:commandButton ...>
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Or if you can't/don't want to use ajax for some unobvious reason, or are still using the legacy JSF 1.x, then check in the `rendered` attribute of `<h:messages>` if the desired form is been [submitted](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html#isSubmitted%28%29) or not.

```
<h:form binding="#{form1}">
    <h:messages rendered="#{form1.submitted}" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton ... />
</h:form>

<h:form binding="#{form2}">
    <h:messages rendered="#{form2.submitted}" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton ... />
</h:form>
```

The `<h:message>` shouldn't have this problem by the way, in contrary to what you're implying in your question.

Comment: @BalusC : When i use your second solution i get the following exceptionn. `javax.servlet.ServletException: Component ID j_idt171:j_idt99 has already been found in the view.`

Comment: @Rasoul: apparently you bound it to a shared bean property for some reason. Do not bind it to a bean and absolutely not to a property which is shared by multiple components. The code in answer is complete as-is. Do not use `#{bean.form1}` or so. Just use `#{form1}`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-binding-attribute-in-jsf-works

Comment: @BalusC your guess is true.I have 2 form in one jsf page and use a shared bean for that forms. I set id for both `<h:messages>`. form1Mess and form2Mess. It return me following exception:  `Component ID contact:form1Mess has already been found in the view.` you thinks there is not any solution except separate forms bean?

Comment: @Rasoul: Do not use `#{bean.form1}` or so. Just use `#{form1}`. You do not need those components in the bean at all.

Comment: @BalusC : I use just #{form1}. see my code : `<h:form binding="#{form1}" id="contact">`  and `<h:form binding="#{form2}" id="personal">`

Comment: @Rasoul: Then it means that you've multiple components bound on the same variable in the same view. Perhaps via include/tagfile/composite?

Comment: @BalusC:  no. i don't have. i think error refer to first h:messages. but this is not important thing. i change my way. i must say big thank to you. you help me and other several time. your are very good. thanks.